# save and read file from MODE_PRIVATE FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard, android-fileprovider

I have one apk file in assets folder.I want to copy apk file from MODE_PRIVATE and then read it.I wrote write and read functions but can't read my file.I have FileNotFoundException
Here is a  my functions

```
 private void writeFilePrivate() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open("test.apk");
        fos = openFileOutput("tmp.apk", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private File readFileFromPrivate() {
    int ch;
    StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("test.apk");
        try {
            while ((ch = fis.read()) != -1)
                fileContent.append((char) ch);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String data = new String(fileContent);
    File file = new File(data);
    return file;
}
```

I have this error in log

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.mypackage.music/files/test.apk: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `have one apk file in assets folder.I want to copy apk file from MODE_PRIVATE ..` No. If it is in assets you want to copy it from assets to some storage location. But you are not telling us where to.

Comment: Place a Toast() in all catch blocks so the user of your app is informed about exceptions.

Comment: `, Context.MODE_PRIVATE`. Remove that. Or use it too if you try to read the file.

Comment: What you mean ? remove file names ? @greenapps

Comment: ??? Who is talking about file names?

Comment: I did not understand your answer @greenapps

Comment: Well i had three comments. So you could react at least three times. What is it that you do not understand?